# Failing to pull latest source from Git

Tags: git

This is the message I get :

> " It seems that I cannot create a
>   rebase-apply directory, and I wonder
>   if you are in the middle of patch
>   application or another rebase.  If
>   that is not the case, please  rm -fr
>   /Users/tom/Documents/Source/mediaplayer2
>   copy/.git/rebase-apply and run me
>   again.  I am stopping in case you
>   still have something valuable there."

The only thing I did prior was to stage and commit.
Don't think I rebased anything.

How do I fix that ? it happened to me couple of times already.

Thanks

Comment: I think you'll need to add some more information, such as: 1. Exactly what command were you running that produced that error?  2. Does the directory it mentions actually exist?  3. Is your .git directory definitely writable by you?  4. What version of git are you using?

Comment: I just "git pull". Maybe I should have done something about rebase, I don't really know,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may happen if you did `git pull --rebase`, it failed (with conflict) and you did neither `git rebase --continue` after fixing the conflicts nor `git rebase --abort` to clean it up. If you recovered via other means (like `git reset` or something), the rebase is still open, but most operations don't do anything with it, so they didn't complain.

Comment: I just did "git rebase --continue" , but now all the files I commited are gone from the file system. how do I get them back ?

Comment: @Idan: Again, I think we need more information. Clearly you made some commit(s) which removed certain files, or checked out a branch on which they weren't committed, or something. Look through your history in `gitk`. Look at the output of `git status`.